# Program of addition in system programming

Tags: operating-system, system, opcode

need to know how does system programming programs work. i am stuck with a program of addition of two numbers and its opcodes. can someone explain it to me with opcodes and how do we obtain opcodes and explanation of each and every statement.
the program is:

```
READ A
READ B
MOVER AREG, A
ADD AREG, B
MOVEM AREG,result
PRINT result
END
DS 1
DS 1
DS 1
```

this is what i have in my notes. but i can't understand it. and what does DS 1 which is repeated three times have to do with the program. how is it related to the program.

Comment: I have no idea what this is: no idea what this has to do with system programming, no idea what architecture this is (it seems it's pseudocode, though), so no idea how you want to retrieve opcodes. You need to explain a lot more and put this into context, where you got it from and what architecture it is. There should be a manual or reference somewhere if this is really an established instruction set you are using there.

Comment: Its in my syllabus of subject system programming. they are teaching from basic. so they'd started from addition of two numbers to show how system programming works. there is lot more in the syllabus. but i'm stuck at this.

Comment: System programming denotes whatever programming is involved to get the machine running and manage it, so basically the stuff done in kernels and operating systems. Your code contains none of that, so I don't see the connection to system programming here: adding two numbers should not really be your most pressing concern in system programming. Second, opcodes are the numbers associated to an instruction. One thing an assembler does is map mnemonics to opcodes, but opcodes are not obtainable merely by reading code without even knowing what architecture the code is run on.

Comment: Either you are confusing terminology here or you are just not providing enough detail. Either way, please fix that in your answer, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.